# I'm not so much of a drinker

Tags: american-english

Is this idiomatic?

**I'm not so much of** a drinker, so when I get out I always look for good service and cheap food.

Answer (score 4):

Using "so" in the phrase invites a comparison.

The slightly simpler

> I'm not much of a drinker

will do.

Comment: At least in my area (Alberta, Canada) all of "not so much of", "not that much of", and your suggestion of "not much of" would be equivalent, and I don't think any of them would be considered unusual.